# ProcessStartInfo WaitForExit Timeout

Tags: c#, asp.net, process

I need to print a pdf-file with `ProcessStartInfo`.

```
 string docInvoicePath = @"[Path]";
 string printername = "\"PRN-OFFICE\"";
 string driver = "\"Xerox Global Print Driver PS\""; 
 string port = "\"[IP]\"";

 ProcessStartInfo psInfo = new ProcessStartInfo
 {
     FileName = @"""C:\Program Files (x86)\Adobe\Reader 9.0\Reader\AcroRd32""",
     Arguments = String.Format("/s /o /h /t " + docInvoicePath + " " + printername + " " + driver + " " + port),
     Verb = "print",
     WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden,
     CreateNoWindow = true,
     UseShellExecute = false                 
 };

 Process process = Process.Start(psInfo);
 process.WaitForExit(6000);
 if (process.HasExited == false)
 {
     process.Kill();
 }
 process.Close();
```

The `filename` and `arguments` are correct they work when pasted in `cmd`.
The code works properly but after `Process.Start` when it comes to `WaitForExit` the programm doesn`t finish. I get the timeout error:

> System.Threading.ThreadAbortException: Thread was being aborted.
>       at System.Threading.WaitHandle.WaitOneNative(SafeHandle waitableSafeHandle, UInt32 millisecondsTimeout, Boolean
>   hasThreadAffinity, Boolean exitContext)
>        at System.Threading.WaitHandle.InternalWaitOne(SafeHandle waitableSafeHandle, Int64 millisecondsTimeout, Boolean
>   hasThreadAffinity, Boolean exitContext)
>       at System.Diagnostics.Process.WaitForExit(Int32 milliseconds)...

I searched and try a few things like setting `<httpRuntime executionTimeout="300"/>` and run into a **500** or like in the code with `process.WaitForExit(6000);` and higher ther where no exeption but nothing got printed.

Is there an error or am i missing something?

**EDIT:**
I changed my codeblock above. Now the code works in debug mode but it still won´t print my document when published. I also tried to use a different User.
In debug mode the code prints the document but runs in the *kill* query.

The `ProcessStartInfo.Verbs` returns a  **Argument Exception** but i don´t know why.

Comment: Are you blocking the main thread?

Comment: i don`t think so, how can i check this ?

Comment: I was just wondering why it should be aborted and if in ASP.NET I am not sure what happens if you block the main thread for so long. In an ordinary .net/WinForms app your GUI would be unresponsive. But on ASP - I do not really know if there are mechanisms to abort long running stuff. Do you have to wait for exit for some reason? If not just omit it. If yes, try doing all this on a worker thread and see if the abort happens there, too.

Comment: without WaitForExit it perfectly runs the code but nothing happens / gets printed

Comment: Hmmm, sorry. I am really not familiar with ASP. Any suggestion from my side would only be applicable to "ordinary" .net Applications. I *suspect* you have to spawn a background task, though.

Comment: There may be more to be done ... See this question: https://stackoverflow.com/q/8061362/982149

Comment: try with `UseShellExecute = false;`

Comment: `UseShellExecute = false;` didn´t work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a lot of trying, testing and searching i am sure my code works. 
So i still don´t really know why my code stoped working. 
But changing from Adobe Reader 9.0 on the server to 7.0 it now works.

When i was debuging locally with Adobe Reader 9.0 it also worked, so i think maybe there was an update on the webserver. I diden`t verifyed that yet.